# DRF djoser. token is invalid error when i try to login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I use token authorization with djoser in DRF.
I save token in httpOnly cookies:

```
class TokenCreateView(TokenCreateView):

    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token
        
        response = Response() 
        data = token_serializer_class(token).data

        response.set_cookie(
            key = 'access_token', 
            value = data['auth_token'],
            secure = False,
            httponly = True,
            samesite = 'Lax'
        )

        response.data = {"Success" : "Login successfully","data":data}
        return response
```

When I login in two devices, I get the same token. But when I logout in one of device, token becomes not valid. But the second device still has token in cookies. And now it is not authorized,but can't login again, because get "Invalid token".
I know that the token is invalid, but I can't login.
How to solve this problem?
And why it gives the same token to all diveces?